# mongodb aggregate sort does not sort in descending order

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the below query to return count of all queries matching the params and the result..

```
await this.db.collection("shipments").aggregate([
        { "$facet": {
          "data": [
            { "$match": {user_id:this.user_id }},
            { "$skip": parseInt(n) },
            { "$limit": 10 },
            {"$sort":{"shipment.label_created_on":-1}},
          ],
          "count": [
            { "$count": "count" }
          ]
        }}
      ]).toArray()
```

and each document has the below format but for some reason I can't get it to sort in descending order based on the label created date. it just returns it in ascending order. any help?

```
{
    "_id": "t304a705kjfg",
    "user_id": "cae4280ce412614bcbb4167d819625af",
    "shipment": {
        label_created_on: 1555646965
        ...
     },
     ...
}
```

Comment: Could you post you sample data?

Comment: this may not be your issue, but you should probably sort before using skip and limit.

Comment: As @kmdreko says you should sort before using skip and limit

Comment: This is also an incorrect usage of `$facet`. Yes you are limiting results, but really a "total count" for paging or similar is better executed as a separate query. The actual execution of `$facet` would in fact be far slower than two separate requests, even with the response overhead. You'd need to understand the implemented code in MongoDB to understand why, but two separate queries for "total" and paging has been common practice for so many years, so you really should not be deluding yourself that anything new is suddenly better, And again, *you mean `$sort` before the `$limit` and `$skip`*

Comment: To be clear *"requests in **parallel**"* is what is meant there. And this would be common in event driven frameworks. Like NodeJS.